# How add more domains to a wildcard domain in amazon route 53?

Tags: apache, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

With a wildcard domain *.exemple.com

the cname is pointing to exemple.com

how to *.exemple.com pointing to www.exemple.com, to support.exemple.com, and etc...?

i need create more cname?

Comment: I thought you meant you wanted all subdomains to point to exemple.com. You only have a few subdomains you want to support (e.g. only www and support)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Amazon Route 53 FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Support_for_wildcard_entries) explains that wildcards are supported in *all* record types:

> To make it even easier for you to configure DNS settings for your domain, Amazon Route 53 supports wildcard entries for all record types.

So you should be able to have a wildcard in a CNAME record.

You should also consider if you prefer to use an [alias in Route 53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html).

Comment: on value,

of cname put all the domains there?

exemple.com
www.exemple.com
support.exemle.com

Comment: I will update my answer if you can clarify what you would like to setup.  I'll mention that Route 53 has the `Test Record Set` capability which might be useful for testing your configuration.

Comment: For a CNAME, the **Name** field is what you want to resolve/point to what is in the **Value** field.  For example, if you want everything to point to exemple.com, the **Name** would be * and the **Value** would be exemple.com